# Three Dimensional Vectors Question

Tags: calculus

Let $\ell_1 , \ell_2 $ be two lines passing through $M_0= (1,1,0) $ that lie on the hyperboloid $x^2+y^2-3z^2 =2 $ .

Calculate the cosine of angle the between the two lines.

I have no idea about it...
I guess it has something to do with the gradient of the function $F(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-3z^2$ that must be perpendicular to our hyperboloid at any point... But how does this help me?

Thanks !

Comment: Let me be sure I understand: you mean there are two lines that cross the hyperboloid at $M_0$ (and no other constraints); then seeking for the ($\cos$)angle between them?

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi No, the lines shall lie completely in the hyperboloid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for two unit vectors $v_,\, v_2$ so that the lines $\ell_i = M_0 + \mathbb{R}\cdot v_i$ are contained in the given hyperboloid. For the components $(a,\,b,\,c)$ of such a $v_i$, inserting into the equation of the hyperboloid yields the condition

$$(1 + t\cdot a)^2 + (1 + t\cdot b)^2 - 3(c\cdot t)^2 = 2$$

for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Expanding the squares, you get a polynomial in $t$ that shall identically vanish, that means all coefficients must vanish, which imposes some conditions on the components of $v_i$ and leaves you with (up to multiplication with $-1$) two possibilities for the $v_i$. You get the cosine of the angle by computing the inner product $\langle v_1 \mid v_2\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the point $M_0$ lies on the equator of the hyperboloid $H$; therefore the surface normal at $M_0$ is given by $n_0=(1,1,0)$. A line $g$ through $M_0$ which completely lies in $H$ would have to be normal to $n_0$ as well; therefore it has a parametric representation of the form
$$g:\quad t\mapsto {\bf r}(t)=(1,1,0)+ t(-1,1,p)\qquad (t\in{\mathbb R})$$
for some $p$ to be determined. Plugging ${\bf r}(t)$ into the equation of $H$ we obtain
$$(1-t)^2+(1+t)^2-3t^2 p^2=2\ ,$$
which should hold identically in $t$. This can indeed be realized by choosing $p$ such that $2-3p^2=0$, i.e., with $p=\pm\sqrt{2/3}$. This shows that two such lines $g\subset H$ in fact exist. The cosine of the angle $\phi$ between them computes to
$$\cos\phi={(-1,1,\sqrt{2/3})\cdot(-1,1,-\sqrt{2/3}) \over
\bigl|(-1,1,\sqrt{2/3})\bigr|\>\bigl|(-1,1,-\sqrt{2/3})\bigr|}={1\over2}\ ;$$
in other words, the angle between the two lines  is $60^\circ$.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!